# Blocked internet traffic for device seems to be leaking out to internet

Tags: networking, internet, iptables, firewall

I have an Ubuntu box that DHCP assigns a static IP address (Based on it's MAC address) at **192.168.2.12** with the Local gateway at 192.168.2.1, **I want to block internet traffic to it and from it**, but **I do** want **local LAN network traffic access to the Ubuntu box (only internally)** .  How can I do this in **iptables** and the **AdvanceTomato router script?**

I tried the commands / syntax below:

```
######## block all internet to ip address but give access to LAN
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.12 -j REJECT

####### Restarts the firewall to update iptables without reboot of router
service firewall restart
```

But it seems to leak out to the internet

```
$ ping att.com

PING att.com (144.160.36.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
64 bytes from att.com (144.160.36.42): icmp_seq=5 ttl=241 time=87.5 ms
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=6 Destination Port Unreachable
64 bytes from att.com (144.160.36.42): icmp_seq=7 ttl=241 time=64.8 ms
From unknown (192.168.2.1) icmp_seq=8 Destination Port Unreachable
64 bytes from att.com (144.160.36.42): icmp_seq=9 ttl=241 time=93.3 ms
```

**Am I using the correct commands / syntax to block the internet of a DHCP assigned static IP, but allow internal LAN network to get to the device?**

For background information I place the commands here.
[image: Firewall script]

Answer (score 0):

I know iptables is a bit irritating at first use, but when you understand what a chain is, it's really easy to use. You should read some tutorials how to use iptables. In the meantime you may use this small iptables.sh script, it should be self explaining.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set default chain policy to ACCEPT everything
/sbin/iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT

# accept all INPUT and OUTPUT from and to the loopback-interface
/sbin/iptables --insert INPUT --in-interface lo --jump ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables --insert OUTPUT --out-interface lo --jump ACCEPT

# rules for chain INPUT
# reject all INPUT which is not from network 192.168.2.0 with subnetmask 255.255.255.0
/sbin/iptables --append INPUT --source !192.168.2.0/24 --jump REJECT

# rules for chain FORWARD
# reject all FORWARD which is not from network 192.168.2.0 with subnetmask 255.255.255.0
/sbin/iptables --append FORWARD --source !192.168.2.0/24 --jump REJECT
# reject all FORWARD which goes not to network 192.168.2.0 with subnetmask 255.255.255.0
/sbin/iptables --append FORWARD --destination !192.168.2.0/24 --jump REJECT

# rules for chain OUTPUT
# reject all OUTPUT which goes not to network 192.168.2.0 with subnetmask 255.255.255.0
/sbin/iptables --append OUTPUT --destination !192.168.2.0/24 --jump REJECT
```

PS I've not tested the script, but it should work.